# Agent service account shows as not clustered

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, clustering, failover

One of the SQL Server 2008 R2 instances I administer is running on a two node Windows Cluster (Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise)
When I run the DMV sys.dm_server_services, SQL Server Service Account shows as Y under the 'is_clustered' column.
However, Agent Service Account is an 'N' for the same field 'is_clustered'. Is it something that I should be worried about and what might be causing this? Does this mean that Agent will not fail over?
Thank you

Comment: IMO the *is_clustered* column is for services that are cluster aware. SQL Server database engine is cluster aware but agent as such is not. It depends on SQL server service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is nothing to be worried about - the Agent isn't considered a clustered service to SQL Server simply because it can't fail over on its own.

You should test a failover and be confident that SQL Server Agent will start on the other node and that jobs will run etc. (sometimes there can be local dependencies that won't exist on the other node(s)), but the DMV itself should not be a concern. I checked several clusters in our environment and they all say Y for the SQL Server service and N for the other services:

> [image]

I can assure you that these clusters fail over correctly and that SQL Server Agent works on all nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but the information provided is simply wrong. The agent is most certainly considered a clustered service and you can see that by looking at the resources in failover cluster manager.

I'm running into a similar problem and stumbled on this thread. In my case it's showing "N" for is_clustered on both the Agent and SQL Server but serverproperty('isclustered') correctly shows 1.

This bug extends from sql 2008 r2 to at least sql 2016. I dont have a more recent FCI to test it on.